# Broken Association Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My models are Bids, Auctions and Company. My `Bid` association to `Auction`s seems to be broken. For some reason `Auction.joins(:bids).where(bids: @bids).to_sql` is giving me

```
"SELECT "auctions".* 
FROM "auctions" 
INNER JOIN "bids" ON "bids"."auction_id" = "auctions"."id" 
WHERE "auctions"."auction_id" IN 
    (SELECT "bids"."id" FROM "bids" INNER JOIN "inventory_parts" ON 
     "bids"."inventory_part_id" = "inventory_parts"."id" 
     WHERE "inventory_parts"."company_id" = 1)"
```

What I'm confused about is why the query has the condition `WHERE "auctions"."auction_id"`. It should be `WHERE "auctions"."id"`

For the sake of brevity, I'm going to list only the Models I believe have a role to play in my issue and the associations I think matter

I have an Auction Model

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_one :auction_part, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :part, through: :auction_part
  has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
```

Bid Model

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company, through: :inventory_part
  belongs_to :auction
  belongs_to :inventory_part
```

and Company Model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :auctions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bids, through: :inventory_parts
  has_many :inventory_parts, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the query to run on `bids.id IN (1,2)`. It should be

```
Auction.joins(:bids).where(bids: {id: @bids})

# OR 

Auction.joins(:bids).where(bids: {id: @bids.pluck(:id)})
```

Comment: So, the `Auction.joins(:bids).where(bids: @bids)` is wrong? Not the associations?

Comment: yes, because whenever you pass `where(column: value)` rails finds the column in current models table. So, in your case `auctions`

Comment: And `bids: @bids` this is the possible reason for the weird query